# HTML Dropdown Returns Blank

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason, my HTML dropdown menu is returning completely blank values. However, you can see the values when you hover your mouse over them. My code is at my GitHub here: https://github.com/kekTEHfrahg/bengalidabbois/blob/master/index.html

EDIT: Sorry, got the wrong link. I fixed it now.

Also, for the specific code with my dropdown:

```
<div translate="no" class="compact marquee" id="div_language">
          <select id="select_language" onchange="updateCountry()">
            <option value="0">Afrikaans</option><option value="1">Bahasa Indonesia</option><option value="2">Bahasa Melayu</option><option value="3">Català</option><option value="4">Čeština</option><option value="5">Dansk</option><option value="6">Deutsch</option><option value="7">English</option><option value="8">Español</option><option value="9">Euskara</option><option value="10">Filipino</option><option value="11">Français</option><option value="12">Galego</option><option value="13">Hrvatski</option><option value="14">IsiZulu</option><option value="15">Íslenska</option><option value="16">Italiano</option><option value="17">Lietuvių</option><option value="18">Magyar</option><option value="19">Nederlands</option><option value="20">Norsk bokmål</option><option value="21">Polski</option><option value="22">Português</option><option value="23">Română</option><option value="24">Slovenščina</option><option value="25">Slovenčina</option><option value="26">Suomi</option><option value="27">Svenska</option><option value="28">Tiếng Việt</option><option value="29">Türkçe</option><option value="30">Ελληνικά</option><option value="31">български</option><option value="32">Pусский</option><option value="33">Српски</option><option value="34">Українська</option><option value="35">한국어</option><option value="36">中文</option><option value="37">日本語</option><option value="38">हिन्दी</option><option value="39">ภาษาไทย</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp; <select id="select_dialect" style="visibility: visible;">
            <option value="en-AU">Australia</option><option value="en-CA">Canada</option><option value="en-IN">India</option><option value="en-NZ">New Zealand</option><option value="en-ZA">South Africa</option><option value="en-GB">United Kingdom</option><option value="en-US">United States</option></select>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS code. Honestly, I don't find anything wrong with it. Is there something wrong with the CSS that makes the dropdown blank?

```
<style>
    .speech {border: 1px solid #DDD; width: 300px; padding: 0; margin: 0}
  .speech input {border: 0; width: 240px; display: inline-block; height: 30px;}
  .speech img {float: right; width: 40px }
  l {
   border: ipx solid black
   }
  /* Style the tabs */
ul.tab {
   list-style-type: none;
   border-radius:10px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}
/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
   background-color:#d9d9d9;
   display: inline-block;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: 0.3s;
   font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
   background-color:#999999 ;
}
/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
   border-radius:10px;
   display: none;
   padding: 6px 12px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-top: none;
}
  /* All content below pertains to the function of the tabs in an "accordian" style */
button.accordion {
   border-radius:26px;
   background-color: #eee;
   color: #444;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 18px;
   width: 100%;
   border: none;
   text-align: left;
   outline: none;
   font-size: 15px;
   transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
}
button.accordion:after {
   content: '>>';
   color: #777;
   font-weight: bold;
   float: right;
   margin-left: 5px;
}
button.accordion.active:after {
   content: "<<";
}
div.panel {
   padding: 0 18px;
   background-color: white;
   max-height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
#info {
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    #div_start {
    float: right;
    }
    #headline {
    text-decoration: none
    }
    #results {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 150px;
    }
    #start_button {
    border: 0;
    background-color:transparent;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .interim {
    color: gray;
    }
    .final {
    color: black;
    padding-right: 3px;
    }
    .button {
    display: none;
    }
    .marquee {
    margin: 20px auto;
    }
    #buttons {
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    }
    #copy {
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
    #copy > div {
    display: none;
    margin: 0 70px;
    }
body, h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif}
.w3-row-padding img {margin-bottom: 12px}
/* Set the width of the sidebar to 120px */
.w3-sidebar {width: 120px;background: #222;}
/* Add a left margin to the "page content" that matches the width of the sidebar (120px) */
#main {margin-left: 120px}
/* Remove margins from "page content" on small screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {#main {margin-left: 0}}
</style>
```

Comment: your code works correct, I checked, may be a css issue over your end!

Comment: Can you try pointing out the CSS issue, please? I would really love that

Comment: Lol how can I until you show me your css ;)

Comment: I fixed the Github link. The CSS is kinda too big to copy and paste here, so just for reference, the style tags start at the 11th line.

Comment: You need to give a working copy of your code. You have 800 lines of code and I cant read mate

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the W3Schools style sheet sets the text color of every element to white (`color: #fff!important;`).

This can be easily remedied with changing the text color for select and option elements:

```
select, option {
    color: black;
}
```

---

You can debug something like this by opening your browser's development tools, right-clicking the element and looking at the CSS used to render the element. In this particular case, your body tag uses the `w3-green` class, which has the following CSS by default:

```
.w3-green, .w3-hover-green:hover {
    color: #fff!important;
    background-color: #4CAF50!important;
}
```

In addition, the normalize style sheet (which has the highest specificity for the select elements) tells the browser to inherit the color from the parent (there's no other color declarations in each of select's parents until it reaches the body tag).

```
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess it actually worked. For this project, I ended up editing a template which came with W3.CSS and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of CSS libraries and they are interfering with each other. Bootstrap.min.css is setting the color of your select to "inherit". Add this after bootstrap's style to fix that.

```
select {color:black;}
```

You can debug your code by using your browser's developer tools and see what style is being applied to your elements and from which library.